# Naming Convention for java final variable which is not static

Tags: java, naming-conventions, final

I have a method in a java class.

```
public void myMethod() {
    final String methodName = "myMethod";
}
```

When I ran this code through an analysis in sonar, I am getting an issue saying

> Rename this constant name to match the regular expression
>   `'^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$'`

My purpose of this variable is to use it in Logger statements to track my application flow.

This variable is not a `static` variable. I have gone through https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252243/naming-convention-final-fields-not-static. But I didn't got a clear picture. Can someone help me to give proper naming convention for my final(not static) variable?

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252243/naming-convention-final-fields-not-static

Comment: A string is immutable. Defining a final variable String with a "raw" value is like defining a constant. Sonar analyze it as a constant and then ask you to match the naming convention of constants. 
You should improve your code by changing this local variable to a constant and then use the right naming convention.
Sonar should be happy with that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are talking about a local variable, scoped to your method.
Local variables follow the naming convention for most Java fields, which is `camelBack`.

Only compile-time constants (`static final` fields declared at class level) "need" to be capitalized, with words separated by an underscore.

Some doc pages:

- [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), and better,
- [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Comment: Fields are on class or instance level. Not at method level - here they are local variables.

Comment: @tbsalling typo, fixed - thanks.

Comment: If this variable define in class level, It should follow camelCase?                            public class MyClass() {
    final String name = "";
}

Answer (score 6):

You have created a local variable, which happens to be final. Therefore your naming is correct, according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html.

Answer (score 1):

In java final variable names are generally declared in all caps with an underscore between words

```
final String METHOD_NAME = "myMethod";
```

Comment: Final variables in java have to match regular expression '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.

Comment: I think that this answer is not correct. This is the convention for static final variables not final variables